# Java long literals

Tags: java, variables, initialization, long-integer, literals

Which one of there expressions are considered java long literals:

1) 0Xf000L

2) 6L

3) (489 - 0L) / 80

4) 30508600000

5) 0XBD000

---

My answer:

1) is considered because of "L" a the end

2) Same as first

3) is not a literal but one calculation ?

4) is to large number for long

5) is not long literal

If I am wrong somewhere please correct me. Also, if the long variable that we are initialising doesn't have "L" at the end is it still considered long literal ? Because if I do that in the compiler it lets me do it(for example 5. question) Thanks!

Comment: 2 and 4 are longs for certain, 3 might be depending on the casting rules (which I forget).  But in any case, can't you test this in your local Java?

Comment: It's very simple: if it doesn't have "L", then it's not a long literal. If it's a calculation rather than a plain number, then it's not a literal.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Not quite...4 doesn't have L, but it is way too large to fit in an int, so it has to be treated as long.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it will just result in a compilation error, but isn´t a long literal itself

Comment: @KevinEsche I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: You are correct. 3 is an *Expression* that evaluates to a long, but not a literal. 4 will give a compile time error, since the value is too large for an int literal

Comment: For the sake of completeness, no. 4 would fit comfortably in a `long` if not for the compile error. If I added `L`, it would be a long literal. As it stands, it is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) and 2) you are completely correct, they are long literals.

3), correct: This is a constant expression of type long. Even though it is a compile-time constant, it does not count as a literal.

4) No, this is not too large to fit in a `long`. However, since it does not have the `L` suffix, it doesn’t count as a `long`. It’s an `int`, but at the same time too large to fit in an `int`, so as discussed in the comments, it’s a compile-time error.

5) is an `int` literal. It can be used wherever a `long` value is expected (e.g., assigned to a `long` variable), but you are correct, this doesn’t make it a long literal.

The basic rule is as RealSkeptic said: “An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).” (here quoted from [JLS section 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)).

(And just to get on a soapbox, the quote continues: The suffix L is preferred, because the letter l (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit 1 (one).)

Comment: Thanks, that is  what I was looking for

Comment: Nothing to thank me for, I just summed up what had already been said in the comments. I just thought it might be nice for future readers, also that it’s clear now that the question has been answered.